# spark-submit to kubernetes cluster on Google cloud got 401 unauthorized

Tags: apache-spark, kubernetes, google-cloud-platform

It's pretty standard spark-submit action, what's weird is that I got 401 from time to time, if I just wait a few minute, I can run again, until next time I got a 401.

it's very similar to this issue 
https://jira.apache.org/jira/browse/SPARK-24227

I'm just wondering if I'm not setting the GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIAL right when submitting, but at the very beginning I haven't set any credential and can still run.

Anyone has similar issues?

Answer (score 1):

It's a subtle bug with Spark couldnt refresh the access token. One work around is:

- Run a dummy kubectl command to refresh access token. E.g: **kubectl get namespace**